# C# (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) Properties

Tags: c#

Visual Studio keeps saying (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) properties are not used and to remove them.  But if I do, it errors out the MainPage.g.cs reference.  What should I do?

```
//MainPage.Xaml.cs    
private void TextBoxSingleArray_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var textBoxSingleArray_GotFocus = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
  textBoxSingleArray_GotFocus.SelectAll();
}

//MainPage.g.cs   
//If I remove object sender, this will display error
((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox)this.TextBoxSingleArray).GotFocus += this.TextBoxSingleArray_GotFocus;
```

Comment: Clean and rebuild the solution.  Failing that, delete /obj and /bin directories and then restart Studio.

Comment: This a `GotFocus` routed event signature, you can't change it when you subscribed to this event. Have a look at [routed events overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview)

Comment: Ignore Visual Studio's advice. I don't believe that's even a warning, just a message.

Comment: Don't forget to pick an answer if one was most helpful. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen messages like that (not in that particular case, though) from ReSharper (do you have that installed?), but Visual Studio itself may also do something similar.

Often, messages like that can help you keep your code cleaner... or sometimes catch bugs because it highlights when something you thought was being used is actually being missed.  But in some cases, such as when creating a library with a public API but that isn't fully used within the same solution and leaves some "public" members unused, a suggestion such as "can be made private" isn't really true--it just has no way of knowing that.

This sounds like a similar case.  You have arguments which are required for an event handler, but until it is used as an event handler somewhere within your code it wouldn't know that and might warn you that they aren't being used.  Or, properties on the RoutedEventArgs aren't being referenced within the handler (or elsewhere in the code that it can see), so it gives you that warning and suggestion.  But really, they are required--just perhaps not within your solution--and you can't really remove properties from a defined event args type that comes from WinForms, anyway.

But, you generally want to take note of messages like and consider whether the suggestion applies or if you have missed using something you should--or maybe you're just still in the middle of coding it and it might go away once you're done.  If it's really a warning (shows up in the Errors box after a build) you may want to suppress it around the unavoidable cases where you know you don't want to access the other properties to "fix" it, but as @HereticMonkey commented, it's probably just a suggestion and not an actual warning.  The main reason to suppress it is so that other, real, warnings aren't missed and can be attended to (or similarly suppressed if not important).  Either way, as long as it's not preventing it from building successfully, you don't have to follow the suggestion--because it's not always right.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time in explaining my case.  I do believe VS is suggesting cleaner code and will take it as suggestion only.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this.

1) Remove the name of the parameters using "discards" . 
REf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards . 
The error you see is due to you are not using those parameters inside the method.

2) Disable the warning: 
Ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning
Ref http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SuppressWarnings.aspx

You just cannot simply remove the parameters since `TextBoxSingleArray_GotFocus` is a referenced event that requires to receive those two parameters. Even if you don't use them.

Hope it helps.
Juan Simon

Comment: I disabled the warning and yes it behaves so much better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get VS to be quite about this by naming your parameters `_` and `__`.

Alternatively, you could add a `SuppressMessage` annotation to your method.

Comment: I am using SuppressMessage and things are better